# chromedriver select item with h1 and p sections in html

Tags: python, css, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this article section with a h1 and p sections representing the product name and the color. Is there any way that I can click on this specific item when two conditions of product name and color name match the expectation by using chromedriver? I was trying to use find_element_by_link_text but it doesn't seem like to work yet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0pwi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Following **xpath** should be able to help you in selecting a particular item based on h1 and p tag properties:

```
//p/a[text()='Red']/parent::p/preceding-sibling::h1/a[text()='Script Logo 6-Panel']/parent::h1/preceding-sibling::a[1]
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to check for the conditions. If the element satisfying the condition is found, then click on it

```
// xpath for element satisfying the condition
String xpath = "//h1/a/[text()= 'Script Logo 6-panel']/../following-sibling::p[1]/a[text()='Red']"

// find the element 
List<WebElement> elements  = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));

// If element is found, click on it.
if (elements.size()!=0) {
    elements.get(0).click();
}
```

The code above is in java. But same can be implemented in python.